# ESLint error in first line store vue 3 with typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, eslint

error:
ESLint: Definition for rule 'valid-appcardcode-code-prop' was not found.(valid-appcardcode-code-prop)

my code in ts store file:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
```

I add `// eslint-disable-next-line valid-appcardcode-code-prop` before first line but also is error ESLint

my code is working and I haven't any error in console, but my IDE (phpStorm) has this error

Comment: fixed this error by commented Internal Rules in eslint: valid-appcardcode-code-prop , valid-appcardcode-demo-sfc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like ESLint tried to use that rule but did not find it. Probably, you have a configuration somewhere that references that rule.